# Can variables in memory by made immune to malicious memory editing?

Tags: variables, memory, anti-cheat

Let's say I am making a game and the player's health is stored in a variable `float player_hp`. While playing the game, a user can open a memory editor like Cheat Engine, do some clever searches through the memory, and find the location of the variable in memory. They can then edit it to be whatever they want, effectively allowing them to cheat.

Is there a fancy way to store my variables that will effectively stop users from maliciously editing them? Should I move them around in memory? Should I encrypt them or hash them?

If it matters, I am primarily using C++.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I have no experience programming games, only making cheats for them.

Calculate all important variables such as health & ammo server side and replicate that data to the client.  Pickups must also be validated by the server.  If you serverside ammo, we'll just call PickUp(ammoCrate) if it's client sided.

You'll never stop everyone but I think it's important to make it annoying enough for 90% of people to stop trying to cheat.  There's some basic stuff every game should have and then more advanced protections that popular games must have to avoid being destroyed by cheaters.

Encrypt commonly modified values such as health with a basic XOR like algorithm that changes over time.  Change address of the key also and use a pointer to it, make the pointer more than 6 layers deep.  This will force cheaters to make a script and use pattern scanning instead just a cheat table, that will stop most people.

Use [IsDebuggerPresent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx) to detect debuggers being attached and then close the process.  When you do "Find What Accesses" in Cheat Engine that will attach a debugger and if using default options will be detected by IsDebuggerPresent.

This can be hooked and patched, the next step is to manually check the BeingDebugged flag in the [Process Environment Block](https://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Process/PEB.html)

**Get PEB pointer:**

```
PEB* GetPEB()
{
#ifdef _WIN64
return (PEB*)__readgsword(0x60); //64 bit

#else
return (PEB*)__readfsdword(0x30); //32bit
#endif
}
```

**Read the debugger flag:**

```
bool IsDebugFlagSet(PEB* peb)
{
    if (peb->BeingDebugged == 1) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

If they're hooking IsDebuggerPresent() you can compare the bytes on disk to the bytes in memory at the beginning of the function and compare, or even easier just check the first byte and see if it's a relative jmp (x86 example)

**Check for Hooks:**

```
bool IsHooked(char* functionName, char* dllName)
{
    BYTE* functionAddress = (BYTE*)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(dllName), functionName);
    return (*functionAddress == 0xE9);
}
```

Other tricks:

Hook LoadLibrary() & LDRLoadDLL() and stop them from loading rogue dlls

Scan running processes for memory editors by comparing the image name or image path using CreateToolHelp32Snapshot() against a blacklist

Fill all debug registers so debugger cannot be attached

Beyond these tricks you can use a commercial anticheat or kernel mode driver to protect your game, but the above tips will stop the average person.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to protect your data:

1) Only provide the user with binary files. Compiled code. Don't give them source code.

2) If your game is an online game, store sensitive data server side.

You should research an idea called "encapsulation" for use in designing APIs such that sensitive data is protected.

Comment: But even in games where the user has only binary files and no source code, it is still possible to use a utility like Cheat Engine to edit the program's memory to malicious ends.

Comment: Generally, people will be able to edit a program on their own machine. The best you can do is often to protect other peoples machines.